# How to view localStorage stored by all domains/websites on your local machine?

Tags: google-chrome

How do we view localstorage saved by all websites/domains on your local machine?

Chrome browser shows localstorage for a particular website when you visit the website.
However, how do I see what got stored on my local chrome browser by all the website I visited?

Comment: This is a very simple and basic question.  Why, after nearly a year, doesn't it have any answers?